# Pylance issues from google-cloud-sdk

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, pylance

Pylance displays errors for Google Cloud SDK after I reinstalled Windows.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Example(ndb.Model):
    basic_example = ndb.StringProperty()
```

The first issue, up by the import:

> Import "google.appengine.ext" could not be resolved *Pylance (reportMissingImports)*

I needed to add extraPaths for Cloud SDK. I've seen/tried various solutions and found this effective:

```
{ // settings.json
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine"
  ],
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine"
  ]
}
```

Current issue, where the library is used; all over the code.

> "Model" is not a known member of module *Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues)*
>
> "StringProperty" is not a known member of module *Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues)*

I see no way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project ran Python 2.7 while Pylance required 3.0.